# Clipped image not drawing next to previous image in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a tile based map I'm trying to draw based on a nested array and a sprite sheet.  When I clip the image, it draws on the canvas, but it doesn't draw next to the previously drawn image.  Here's how it's drawing right now.
[image]

The images need to be resting against each other.  Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong?

**JS**

```
*/*Map array*/*
Basemap = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
*/*Draws the image*/*
spriteSheet.onload = function(){ 
    var tileWidth = 0;
    var tileHeight = 0;
    var destWidth = 0;
    var destHeight = 0;
    var xPos = 0; 
    var yPos = 0; 
    for(var rows = 0; rows < Basemap.length; rows++){
        tileHeight = 360;
        destHeight = tileHeight / 3;
        for(var cols = 0; cols < Basemap[rows].length; cols++){
            tileWidth = 360;
            destWidth = tileWidth / 3;
            if(Basemap[rows][cols] == 0){ 
                basemapCtx.drawImage(spriteSheet, 363, 363, tileWidth, tileHeight, xPos, yPos, destWidth, destHeight); 
            } 
            xPos += tileWidth; 
        } 
        xPos = 0; 
        yPos += tileHeight; 
    } 
    yPos = 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out.  I was setting the xPos and yPos variables wrongly after each for loop.  instead of adding the tileWidth and tileHeight, I needed to add the destWidth, and destHeight like so.

```
for(var rows = 0; rows < Basemap.length; rows++){
    tileHeight = 360;
    destHeight = tileHeight / 3;
    for(var cols = 0; cols < Basemap[rows].length; cols++){
        tileWidth = 360;
        destWidth = tileWidth / 3;
        if(Basemap[rows][cols] == 0){ 
            basemapCtx.drawImage(spriteSheet, 363, 363, tileWidth, tileHeight, xPos, yPos, destWidth, destHeight); 
        } 
        xPos += destWidth; 
    } 
    xPos = 0; 
    yPos += destHeight; 
} 
yPos = 0;
```

}